# HTML5 chart fails to render

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

I'm trying to create a chart using [morris.js](http://www.oesmith.co.uk/morris.js/lines.html). I cannot understand why the data I have rendered will not work. This is the entire function. I get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined`.

[LINK TO MORRIS.JS DEMO](http://jsbin.com/uqawig/441/embed?javascript,live)

```
$(function () {
    Morris.Line({
        element: 'line-example',
        data: [{
            "date": "2014-05-03",
                "71236": "247893",
                "71232": "19520",
                "70555": "16723",
                "33315": "415516",
                "61236": null,
                "62243": null
        }, {
            "date": "2014-05-04",
                "71236": "315174",
                "71232": "19103",
                "70555": "16572",
                "33315": "443728",
                "61236": null,
                "62243": null
        }, {
            "date": "2014-05-05",
                "71236": "265",
                "71232": "469",
                "70555": "519945",
                "33315": "24635",
                "61236": "74245",
                "62243": "568387"
        }, {
            "date": "2014-05-06",
                "71236": "20",
                "71232": "17",
                "70555": "38684",
                "33315": "1794",
                "61236": "3762",
                "62243": "24660"
        }],
        xkeys: 'date',
        ykeys: ["71236", "71232", "70555", "33315", "61236", "62243"],
        labels: ["71236", "71232", "70555", "33315", "61236", "62243"]
    });

});
```

What's wrong with this syntax?

### EDIT

I have now simplified and made as much like the demo as possible, still not working:

```
$(function () {
    Morris.Line({
        element: 'line-example',
        data: [
            {"y": "2011", a: "247893", b: "19520", c: "16723", d: "415516", e: "3", f: "3"}, 
            {"y": "2012", a: "315174", b: "19103", c: "16572", d: "443728", e: "3", f: "3"}, 
            {"y": "2013", a: "265", b: "469", c: "519945", d: "24635", e: "74245", f: "568387"}, 
            {"y": "2014", a: "20", b: "17", c: "38684", d: "1794", e: "3762", f: "24660"}
        ],
        xkeys: "y",
        ykeys: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"],
        labels: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
    });

});
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/uqawig/3185/edit)

Comment: @Johnston I don't understand what's funky about it. What is? The first property is the date it defines, while each additional property has a key that's the id of the line to be drawn and a value that is it's position on the graph. It should look like a line graph with six lines.

Comment: that's why I removed it. It's different because you are using numbers as properties. Trying to create a fiddle.

Comment: @Johnston I've successfully recreated their demo using quoted numbers as keys http://jsbin.com/uqawig/3183/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I know what your main issue is. 
http://jsbin.com/uqawig/3202/edit

You just needed to change 2 things. 
1 take it out of a `jQuery` ready function. (this is not necessary to fix the issue)
2 it's `xkey` not `xkeys`
That is the main issue. Change those two things and you will be good to go. 
Everything else I said before is untrue.

Comment: Yes, but that gives me `undefined` for all of my dates.

Comment: @thomas I figured it out. You had **one** issue. You just had a typo.